# Streaming Player issue in blackberry

Tags: streaming, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am Referring the above example of Streaming Player to understand the Concept of Streaming.
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/05/streaming-player-api/

but when i used this code i got some unexpected errors like when i am clicking on options it shows me an blank screen.and also not able play any media on the same.i searched on this but not got any useful information.i am running this code on JDE 6.0.And also when i click on the play button it gives me an "RIM MEDIA Exception"error.if u have any suggestions please let me know.
Thanks,
Sagar.

Comment: This may be useful for you http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/Playing_media_in_BB_device_app_739576_11.jsp http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11942/RIM_proprietary_video_format_1001586_11.jsp#Buffer_and_play_streamed_media_740033_11